# Reducing the impact on diskspace when loading new software on a dev machine.

Tags: hardware, diskspace

TL;DR

noob wants to setup dev machine/workspace on old hardware using windows 10 and load up 5+ software programs with similar file size and disk impact as Visual Studios. Wants reduce the impact these programs have on his already resource scarce laptop.  Buying new hardware is the last resort, what is a viable workaround?

I have a laptop that I use for school and I am looking into using it as a development work space. (Visual Studio, SSMS, .NET, Jetbrains, Github Desktop, Infragistics Studio and the works) However I also don't want these programs to slow down my regular student workflow (Word, Excel, browser) and take up resources. Additionally some of the development programs I intend to only test drive during their trial period so I don't want them to stick around in my file system.  A lot of the things these programs do overlaps so eventually I will be removing some of the programs that are not a good fit for what I am doing(Training for Web Development).

My area of concern is that Memory usage per Task manager floats around 50% and Disk hits 99% on a regular basis. My goal is to reduce the impact of loading even more software to my computer.  It currently has the basic office programs for school but I think the cause of it being gloated is that it is a 4yr old computer (Lenovo Ideapad Z370) Intel Core i5-2410M dual-core/4GB DDR3-1333 RAM/500GB 5400RPM, which may not be the most optimal hardware to have windows 10 running on.

To address this problem, could I just load my development programs to a external hard drive and then connect it to the laptop only when I am in "developer workflow" ?

I've done some initial looking into and this solution is said to be non-viable solution because programs vary in portability. If this is the case, could you propose alternatives such as loading the programs to a VM and connecting to it when I need the programs? What are other possible solutions to my resource problem?

I have a dropbox account and a onedrive account and a $25 Azure Credit provided by the school which I have at my disposal. Solution should be cost-effective. Goal is to squeeze the last ounce of value of current hardware before upgrading.

Thanks in Advance! @noob

Comment: 1) Putting files on an external drive does not save *memory*. It saves *disk space*, which is not the same. If you're going to do any development, it's extremely important to learn the difference. 2) Whether it's possible or not is far too broad in scope. It would depend on the specific *development programs* you're going to use. Some can be installed portably (to be used on different machines from external storage) and some can not. 3) A vague request to *feel free to mention things* is not an appropriate question here. Spend some time in the [help], particularly [ask].

Comment: Question has been edited, could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Hello All I found what I was looking for!

Azure Cloud has a "Developer Ready" image.  The VM holds Visual studios and other helpful tools preloaded. However you need to have a MSDN subscription and a Window 10 Professional product key.  I had neither so I went with another option of a VM with preloaded SQL Server.  From there I was able to load up all the demoware and tools as well as SSMS.  I can now access my tools through RDP from work, home, school, any other MS machine. Best of all, now I don't need to buy new hardware and the pay per minute use keeps the price within my allotted credits from Azure.

TL;DR
Free VM to tap into my dev space and develop from anywhere